# How do I get properties that ONLY have populated values?

Tags: powershell, quest

How do I get properties that ONLY have populated values?

So for example if I run

```
Get-QADUser -Identity "SomeOne" -IncludeAllProperties
```

the output would of course include.. all properties, including those with and those without values. I want a listing of properties with values only. How is it done generally speaking?

This wouldn't be restricted to Quest Cmdlets, I only use `Get-QADUser` as an example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try using the built-in (hidden) property of PowerShell objects called **PSObject**, which includes a property called **Properties**, i.e. a list of all properties on the parent object.

Maybe easier with an example. Take `Get-Process`... a process can have many attributes (properties) with or without values. In order to get just the ones with values you do this:

```
(Get-Process | Select -First 1).PSObject.Properties | ?{$_.Value -ne $null} | FT Name,Value
```

Note that I limited this to just the first process returned by `Get-Process`. We then get all the properties defined on that object, filtering where **Value** is not null and then displaying just the **Name** and **Value** for those properties.

Comment: This is a better approach :)

Comment: @Vesper: Specifically, this answer's approach is more concise, performs better (because no `Get-Member` call is needed), and implicitly also includes `NoteProperty` members.
The `.psobject.properties` approach would also make it easier to exclude (rarely seen) write-only properties: `?{ $_.IsGettable -and $_.Value -ne $null }`

Comment: You might want to exclude empty strings too.  `''`

Answer (score 11):

To *complement* [Charlie Joynt's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44370775/45375):

Below is **convenience function `Remove-NullProperties`**, which creates custom-object copies of its input objects populated with only the non-`$null` properties of the input objects.

Example use:

```
# Sample input collection, with 2 objects with different $null-valued
# properties.
$coll = [pscustomobject] @{ one = 'r1c1'; two = $null; three = 'r1c3' },
        [pscustomobject] @{ one = 'r2c1'; two = 'r2c2'; three = $null }

# Output copies containing only non-$null-valued properties.
# NOTE: The `ForEach-Object { Out-String -InputObject $_ }` part is solely
#       there to ensure that *all* resulting properties are shown.
#       With the default output, only the properties found on the FIRST
#       input object would be used in the output table.
$coll | Remove-NullProperties | 
  ForEach-Object { Out-String -InputObject $_ }
```

This yields the following - note how the respective null-valued properties were removed:

```
one  three
---  -----
r1c1 r1c3 


one  two 
---  --- 
r2c1 r2c2
```

---

**`Remove-NullProperties` source code:**

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Removes properties with $null values from custom-object copies of 
the input objects.

.DESCRIPTION
Note that output objects are custom objects that are copies of the input
objects with copies of only those input-object properties that are not $null.

CAVEAT: If you pipe multiple objects to this function, and these objects
        differ in what properties are non-$null-valued, the default output
        format will show only the non-$null-valued properties of the FIRST object.
        Use ... | ForEach-Object { Out-String -InputObject $_ } to avoid
        this problem.

.NOTES
Since the output objects are generally of a distinct type - [pscustomobject] -
and have only NoteProperty members, use of this function only makes sense
with plain-old data objects as input.

.EXAMPLE
> [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = $null; three = 3 } | Remove-NullProperties

one three
--- -----
  1     3

#>
function Remove-NullProperties {

  param(
    [parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
    [psobject] $InputObject
  )

  process {
    # Create the initially empty output object
    $obj = [pscustomobject]::new()
    # Loop over all input-object properties.
    foreach($prop in $InputObject.psobject.properties) {
      # If a property is non-$null, add it to the output object.
      if ($null -ne $InputObject.$($prop.Name)) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $obj -NotePropertyName $prop.Name -NotePropertyValue $prop.Value
      }
    }
    # Give the output object a type name that reflects the type of the input
    # object prefixed with 'NonNull.' - note that this is purely informational, unless
    # you define a custom output format for this type name.
    $obj.pstypenames.Insert(0, 'NonNull.' + $InputObject.GetType().FullName)
    # Output the output object.
    $obj
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

These answers didn't work for me in the case of importing an object from an Infoblox csv file.  Some values were the empty string, but not null.  Testing whether a property is true or not, seems to work better for me.  And the result is an object.

```
$a = [pscustomobject]@{one='hi';two='';three='there'}
$prop = $a.psobject.Properties | where value | foreach name
$a | select $prop

one three
--- -----
hi  there
```

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this approach. While it might not catch every variation of null, blank, etc.; I will definitely start using this idea in interactive coding.  I think its very handy for getting your head around new datasets.

Comment: For objects imported from a CSV file, this works (CSV field values are all _strings_), but beware of objects that have _numeric_ properties with value `0`, which would be excluded too.

Answer (score 0):

You first get its properties (since `Get-QADUser` depends on AD schema, the properties list is dynamic) with `get-member -type property`, then filter out those that don't have `\{.*(get).*\}` in its definition (that is, they are not "gettable"), then enumerate the resultant list by name and filter out nulls.

```
$someone=Get-QADUser -Identity "SomeOne" -IncludeAllProperties
$members=$someone|get-member -type property| where {$_.definition -match '\{.*(get).*\}'}
foreach ($member in $members) {
    if ($someone[$member.name] -ne $null) {
        write-host $member.name $someone[$member.name] 
    }
}
```

Comment: Kudos for trying to exclude write-only properties, although chances of running into them in a PowerShell context are slim; `-match '\{get;'` would do.
If you wanted to generalize this to include `NoteProperty` members, use `-Type Properties` (plural), but there the `-match` test wouldn't work (and isn't needed).
To promote good habits, can I suggest you [avoid the use of `Write-Host`](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/) and use something like `$member.name + ': ' + $someone[$member.name]` as the output statement?