# How to remove the entire row when any one field of CVS is null in powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

```
ProcessName UserName             PSComputerName

AnyDesk     NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM  localhost
csrss                            dc-01
ctfmon      SAD\Administrator    rdscb-01
            SAD\Administrator    srv-01
```

Remove the second and last row here

Comment: This is a programmer's Q&A site; I don't see a question or any code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   ---  Show your code and errors.  This is not a complicated thing you are after, as there are many articles on the use case of file and string parsing (csv/txt), on the web and videos on Youtube, using comparison operators, Select-String, ConvertFrom-String cmdlets or RegEx. We can help, but we need to see what you've done so far.

Comment: @postanote I can do this by just using "-ne" for every row but that seems too much to me so I just want to get a dynamic solution. I didn't find any dynamic solution.

" $data = $data | Select-Object ProcessName, UserName, PSComputerName | Where-Object{$_.UserName -ne ""} | Format-Table "

Comment: Your collection may have _come from_ a CSV file, but I don't think this is a CSV-specific question.  [How do I get properties that ONLY have populated values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44368990/150605) gets close, but filters out empty properties instead of objects with empty properties.

Comment: Not really, since you are importing a csv file, it is coming in one row at a time, thus process each row is a prudent thing to do. Yet it sounds like you are asking, that you want to dynamically capture all columns regardless of the number returned, use the header name in processing the rows one at a time while using that capture columnname to validate content of that cell. This requires reqined the file, capturing the columns then process it lines. So, at minimum, you'll need to counters for the loop. This still menas either -not or -ne per row, while dynamically grabbing column headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your comments, if `$data` is read from a CSV file and contains custom objects, you can do the following:

```
$data | where { $_.PsObject.Properties.Value -notcontains $null -and $_.PsObject.Properties.Value -notcontains '' }
```

This will apply to every property and won't require supplying named properties.

Comment: ;-}  --- Like I said above, more elegant ways exist, as AdminOfThings is showing. ---  ;-}

Comment: Thanks, @AdminOfThings it seems to be working but it didn't work when I just used "-ne" instead of "-notcontains".

Comment: Yes, you can't use `-ne` with `$_.PsObject.Properties.Value` because `.Value` is going to return a collection. `-notcontains` is used for containment to compare a single item against a collection of items.

Answer (score 1):

There are more elegant ways, but, here is a kind of ugly answer, to illustrate this...

```
$Data = @"
"ProcessName","UserName","PSComputerName"
"AnyDesk","NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM","localhost"
"csrss","","dc-01"
"ctfmon","SAD\Administrator","rdscb-01"
 "","SAD\Administrator","srv-01"
"@ | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\ProcData.csv'

$headers = (
    (Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\ProcData.csv') -replace '"','' | 
    select -First 1
) -split ','

$data    = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\ProcData.csv'
$colCnt  = $headers.count
$lineNum = 0

:newline
foreach ($line in $data)
{
    $lineNum++
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $colCnt; $i++)
    {
        # test to see if contents of a cell is empty
        if (-not $line.$($headers[$i]))
        {
            Write-Warning -Message "$($lineNum): $($headers[$i]) is blank"
            continue newline
        }
    }
    "$($lineNum): OK"
    # Perform other actions with good data
}

<#
# Results

1: OK
WARNING: 2: UserName is blank
3: OK
WARNING: 4: ProcessName is blank
#>
```

Comment: I think that's a very direct approach. Definitely worth showing compared to the more elegant approaches :-).

Comment: Thx..... Options, options, options. We all need them; when we need them.     ;-}